# How will I pass a refrence of a variable, to the second funciton once the first function has called the second function inside of the first function?

Tags: javascript, ajax

In the change_text() function I am trying to pass it the xmhttp.responsetext variable.. but how will I do this? As I see no way yet on how to pass it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax(url, func) {
    this.url = url;
    var xmlhttp =  new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 2 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            this.func = func;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open();
    xmlhttp.send()
}

function change_text() {
    target = document.getElementById("x");
       target.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}

ajax("url.php", change_text);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, to do this you don't want to use `this` at all, since you are not creating any instances of an object and it doesn't act like a constructor.

You can just:

```
function ajax(url, func) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            // note: loaded is 4 ^
            func(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    //            ^~~ you also forgot to pass parameters here
    xmlhttp.send('');
}
```

That would make the `ajax` function work.

For your `change_text` function, it's not in the same function as `ajax`, so it does not have access to the `xmlhttp` variable. However, the `ajax` function passed the responseText to it, so just make your function receive it:

```
function change_text(responseText) {
    var target = document.getElementById("x");
//  ^~~ don't forget to declare local variables with `var`.
    target.innerHTML = responseText;
}
```

For a working example, see the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycnD2/).

Comment: Calling a constructor function without a new keyword results in pollution of global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.func = func;` to `this.func = function () { func(xmlhttp.responseText); };`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax(url, func) {
    this.url = url;
    var xmlhttp =  new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 2 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            func(xmlhttp);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open();
    xmlhttp.send()
}

function change_text(xmlhttp) {
    target = document.getElementById("x");
       target.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}

ajax("url.php", change_text);
</script>
```

You have to call your callback with parameters. Also note that `this.url = url` just sets `window.url = url` which is probably a bug.

You probably want `xmlhttp.open("POST", url)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

*Mike Samuel* is almost correct, but `change_text` is missing an argument, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajax(url, func) {
    this.url = url;
    var xmlhttp =  new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //did you mean: func(xmlhttp.responseText);
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 2 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            this.func = function() {
                 func(xmlhttp.responseText);
            };
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open();
    xmlhttp.send()
}

function change_text(responseText) {
    target = document.getElementById("x");
target.innerHTML = responseText;
}

ajax("url.php", change_text);
</script>
```